# Find the number of solutions of $x + y + z + w = 1$ in integers greater than -4

Tags: combinatorics

> Find the number of solutions of $x + y + z + w = 1$ in integers greater than -4, i.e., in integers selected from -3, - 2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...

I have a question regarding the above question, which according to the book(maths of choice) has the answer $\binom{16}{3}$. From my understanding, for none negative integer $\binom{n+k-c_1-c_2,...-c_k-1}{r-1}$ is used. However, the answer seems to be derived from the same formula, or am I supposed to start counting from -4 which would gives the same answer with $\binom{n-c_1-c_2-...-c_k-1}{r-1}$;

using $\binom{n+k-c_1-c_2,...-c_k-1}{r-1}$ 
#r = x + 3 
#s = y + 3 
#t = z + 3 
#u = w + 3 
sum to 12

$\binom{1+4+12-1}{4-1}$ or $\binom{16}{3}$

or

using $\binom{n-c_1-c_2-...-c_k-1}{r-1}$ 
#r = x + 4 
#s = y + 4 
#t = z + 4 
#u = w + 4 
sum to 16

$\binom{1+16-1}{4-1}$ or $\binom{16}{3}$

Kindly advise

Comment: Your two approaches are essentially the same.  The first adds $3$ to each of the four numbers (so adds $12$ to the total) and asks how many *non-negative solutions* to $r+s+t+u=13$.  The second adds $4$ to each of the four numbers (so adds $16$ to the total) and asks how many *positive* solutions to $r+s+t+u=17$. These are equivalent (try stars-and-bars or add $1$ for each value in a solution in the non-negative case to get a solution in the positive case) and so give the same answers, as they must.

Comment: For what it's worth, I regard the enumeration of the solutions to $$x_1 + \cdots + x_k = n ~: ~x1,\cdots,x_k \in \Bbb{Z^+}$$  to be a *derived* result of the enumeration of the solutions to $$x_1 + \cdots + x_k = n ~: ~x1,\cdots,x_k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$$  So, given a choice, I generally steer for the 2nd equation above... Just my personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct.  You have demonstrated that there is a $1$-$1$ correspondence between solutions of the given equation and solutions in non-negative integers of $r+s+t+u=13$.  That correspondence is obtained via $x=r-3, y=s-3, z=t-3, w=u-3$.  Stars and bars shows that the latter equation has $\binom{16}{3}$ solutions.

Comment: thank you for the reply. Both equations have the same solution $\binom{16}{3}$; however, the latter(second) equation starts counting at -4 and the first equation starts counting at -3. In your answer, you mentioned the latter equation which counts from -4 instead of -3. Hence, I'm confuse as to which are you referring to as the correct answer?

Comment: @ManOnTheMoon  Please read Henry's comment below your question.

Comment: I've voted on his comment. Thank you again for recommending "maths of choice"